# mysql escape special 4 characters in my query

Tags: mysql, char, escaping

now i'm testing mysql escape special characters(`\,_,%,'`).

-table real data-

```
\test
_test
%test
'test
```

-my query-

1.

```
    select * from user_name where user_name LIKE '\test%' escape '|'
```

2.

```
    select * from user_name where user_name LIKE '_test%' escape '_' (underscope)
```

3.

```
    select * from user_name where user_name LIKE '%test%' escape '%'
```

4.

```
    select * from user_name where user_name LIKE ''test%' escape '''
```

but just first query is success result. and just multiple escape was not running

- multiple escape query -

  ```
  select * from user_name where user_name = '\test%' escape ('|' || '%' || '_' || ''')
  ```

please advise for my query. and i want to [insert value] just 4 case.
(for example, under the 4 insert value not test case.

```
 \\test
 \_test
 \%test
 \'test
```

)

Comment: please do format your code

Comment: In **what** language?

Comment: now i'm just testing mysql query in MySQL workbanch

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL `LIKE` operator like below which will eventually match the special characters as well. See a [Live Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41a0e/2)

```
select * from user_name where user_name LIKE '%test%'
```

Comment: @MinSubso, use `LIKE` operator present in MySQL. See a demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41a0e/2

Comment: Thank you. now i'm testing your demo link. but i want to real data. if table data [%test], search query result just one [%test].

Comment: one search input -> one search result.

Comment: @MinSubso, you can as well use `\\` operator for escaping special character. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html